# Serial swap support in sming

Tags: sming

Is serial swap supported in sming on esp8266? I looked through libraries but could not see any methods I thought was relevant.
If so are there any examples available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used chocolatey to install sming on Windows, this installed sming v2.1. I proceeded to clone latest sming v3.2 and found serial swap is now supported.
Just in case anyone else finds this useful.